# Program to batch unlock PDF files to make them OCRable in Acrobat

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, offline, batch

I am looking for a gratis, off-line program on Microsoft Windows to batch unlock PDF files to make them OCRable in Acrobat.

---

I unsuccessfully tried https://sourceforge.net/projects/portablepdfunlocker/: it doesn't work on my PDF files, it displays "working x of y file" forever:

[image: Screenshot of Portable PDF Unlocker not working]

(I tried with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate)

To remove the security on just 1 PDF one can use Chrome -> save as PDF. But I couldn't find a way to batch process with Chrome: [How can I save many PDF files as PDF files via Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/q/1572824/116475) (unless using some ad hoc AHK/Sikuli/etc. scripts)

Comment: Franck, about how many files are you talking about?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket 120

Comment: I did some searching for you. I didn't find exactly what you want (hopefully someone else will), but in the meantime, will this help you?: https://github.com/jingyu9575/sumatrapdf-nodrm-unofficial  I'm thinking perhaps that project in conjunction with a simple script.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Thanks, to remove the security on just 1 PDF one can otherwise use Chrome. But I couldn't find a way to batch process with Chrome: [How can I save many PDF files as PDF files via Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/q/1572824/116475) (unless using some ad hoc AHK/Sikuli/etc. scripts)

Comment: I'm thinking you'll be able to use AHK/Sikuli with the project I found along with either a batch file, PowerShell, or python to get it done.  Not the prettiest, but should be fairly easy (if the project I found works for your files... which I think it likely will).  I'm not sure how much it buys you more than Chrome except it should be much faster and lighter on resources (and, of course, it's completely open source!).

Comment: I just thought of an interesting idea.  What about printing them all to a virtual printer (such as a virtual PDF printer) and processing the results?  I'm not sure it would work, but it may.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket thank you, good point. I am trying to do so from Acrobat, but not success so far: [How can I create an Adobe Acrobat action that prints a PDF as a PDF without any user prompt?](https://superuser.com/q/1574338/116475). I'll try with some other programs and try to convince Microsoft Windows Explorer that "print" should go to PDFCreator (sounds possible according to https://forums.pdfforge.org/t/does-not-print-in-batch-pdf/11302/3) but other suggestions welcome. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: ok I got it working with [PDFCreator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFCreator)

Comment: I'm glad you got it working Franck.  I've never used PDFCreator, and I've added it onto my list of software to review.  I don't see a manually installed version.  Do you know if there is one?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket what do you mean by "manually installed version"?

Comment: Either portable (no writing to the registry or folders outside of its own) or sans installer (may write to the registry or other folders, but all files are initially copied by the user manually).

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket got it, unlikely as it comes with a virtual printer which is quite invasive, but I haven't tried to search for it

Comment: Thanks Franck.  I was using a similar tool, PDF24, but the installer was just too sketchy to continue using it.  Every time I updated it, I would have to spend 20-30 minutes making sure it didn't mess anything up.  I think the people at PDF24 are likely trying to do a good thing, but their implementation is very questionable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PDFCreator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFCreator):

- gratis
- offline
- works on Windows 10, Windows 8, Windows 7 SP1

To batch unlock PDF files to make them OCRable in Acrobat, batch print them via PDFCreator. To batch print in PDFCreator, see https://www.pdfforge.org/tips/auto-save

[image]

[image]

[image]

Tested with [PDFCreator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFCreator) 4.1.2 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Note that by default PDFCreator comes with PDF Architect. If you don't want it, you can  unselect during the installation process:

[image]

[image]